# Update crawl-delay in the Shopify robots.txt file

Tags: shopify

I wan't to update the crawl-delay in the Shopify robots.txt file

Here is the robots.txt file content.
[Robots.txt content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXgYR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXgYR.png)

I don't know where I can update the crawl delay.

I have no idea how to do that, if anyone know please reply,
Thanks!